# Change directory name or path inside echo on link click with php

Tags: php, jquery

Iam trying to create artist gallery. Gallery is created but when i need to have 50 artists, i have to create 50 pages. So i need to change only direction to folder after link is clicked.
What is the best way to do it ?
Link to my gallery
http://www.divart.sk/vg/krajina.php

links to artists

```
<option value="http://www.divart.sk/vg/krajina.php">krajina</option>
<option value="http://www.divart.sk/vg/virtualgallery.php">Adina Chitu</option>
```

php code

```
$dir = "krajina/";
if (is_dir($dir)){
  if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){
      if( $file == '.' || $file == '..')
        continue;
      echo " <div><img src='krajina/" . $file . "'/></div>";
    }
    closedir($dh);
  }
}
```

Comment: Does the code you provided work? If yes and `$file` is sent via POST or GET, you probably should keep a static array in your PHP code with the available galleries, and check `$file` against it, to avoid security problem with people trying to acces other of the site's files

Comment: The code works at the moment as you can see after click link to page. Iam begginer in php.

Comment: When i click button <option value="">krajina</option> i would like to change text in $dir = "here/"; and echo " <div><img src='here/" . $file . "'/></div>";  and problem is solved..Propably is not possible and iam wery wrong

Comment: If I understand well you mean that the value in `$dir = "here/";` should change for every artist?

Comment: if it is in one page you can use pure js if it changes to another page you can use session with js

Comment: Every artist has one folder with images. I'd like to load only images to page, I don't want to create so many pages. I guess I have to change value in $dir and also  inside echo link.

Comment: Use jquery would be the best for loading images after click.

Comment: Using jquery would be the best to change piece of php code in one page or change variable for acces to folder. @fmsthird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do simple by passing the **folder name** to **php script** via `Query String` using ([Parse String](https://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)) and [ScanDir](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php).

You'll have to create this structure:

`http://www.divart.sk/vg/gallery.php?dir=the_artist_folder`

`http://www.divart.sk/vg/krajina/`

`http://www.divart.sk/vg/nicole/`

`http://www.divart.sk/vg/jonathan/`

Where the **folder name** is the **folder artist**, while the `gallery.php` is the **php script** that read the **folder artist**!

As requested in the comments, you can add **artist info** by loading a text file (is not the best way) put inside the folder artist, example:

`http://www.divart.sk/vg/krajina/artist.txt`

`http://www.divart.sk/vg/nicole/artist.txt`

`http://www.divart.sk/vg/jonathan/artist.txt`

Example of text file `artist.txt`:

```
Artist: krajina;
Born: 1967/04/18;
Photo Genre: Nature;
License Photo: Creative Commons;
```

For example: `<option value="http://www.divart.sk/vg/gallery.php?dir=krajina">krajina</option>`

`gallery.php`

```
<?php ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="distribution" content="global">
  <meta name="language" content="italian it">
  <meta name="language" content="english en">
  <meta name="rating" content="general">
  <meta name="revisit-after" content="6 days">
  <meta name="pragma" content="no-cache">
  <meta name="robots" content="index, nofollow">
  <title>Gallery</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="gallery.css">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
</head>

<body>

<?php
  // example: http://www.divart.sk/vg/gallery.php?dir=krajina
  // rev .04 (23.04.2019)
  function file_get_contents_utf8($fn) {
    $content = file_get_contents($fn);
    return mb_convert_encoding($content, 'UTF-8', mb_detect_encoding($content, 'UTF-8, ISO-8859-1', true));
  }
  $gurl = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  $ourl = array();
  $list = array();
  parse_str($gurl, $ourl);
  $valid_artist = array("krajina", "nicole", "jonathan");
  if (isset($ourl['dir']) || (!empty($ourl['dir']))) {
    if (!in_array($ourl['dir'], $valid_artist)) {
      exit("This artist name isn't allowed");
    }
    if ((!file_exists($ourl['dir'])) || (!is_dir($ourl['dir']))) {
      exit("This folder doen't exist!");
    }
    if (preg_match('/[\s]/', $ourl['dir'])) {
      exit("Detected white space, please don't use it");
    } else {
      $dir = htmlspecialchars($ourl['dir'], ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    }
  }
  if ((isset($dir)) || (!empty($dir))) {
    if (file_exists("$dir/artist.txt") && is_file("$dir/artist.txt")) {
      $artist = file_get_contents_utf8("$dir/artist.txt");
      $artist = htmlentities($artist, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
      echo "<div>$artist</div>\n";
    }
    $list = scandir($dir);
    foreach ($list as $file) {
      if (is_file($dir . '/' . $file)) {
        $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        if ($ext == 'gif' || $ext == 'jpeg' || $ext == 'jpg' || $ext == 'png') {
          echo "<div>\n<img src=\"" . $dir . '/' . $file . "\" alt=\"" . $dir . "\"><br />\n</div>\n";
          echo "<div>\nPhoto: " . basename($file) . "<br />\n</div>\n";
        }
      }
    }
  } else {
    echo "No Artist Folder to Show!";
  }
?>

</body>

</html>
```

If you see the **html source** generated by Php you can see:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="distribution" content="global">
  <meta name="language" content="italian it">
  <meta name="language" content="english en">
  <meta name="rating" content="general">
  <meta name="revisit-after" content="6 days">
  <meta name="pragma" content="no-cache">
  <meta name="robots" content="index, nofollow">
  <title>Gallery</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="gallery.css">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
</head>

<body>

<div>Artist: krajina;
Born: 1967/04/18;
Photo Genre: Nature;
License Photo: Creative Commons;</div>
<div>
<img src="krajina/001.jpg" alt="krajina"><br />
</div>
<div>
Photo: 001.jpg<br />
</div>
<div>
<img src="krajina/002.jpg" alt="krajina"><br />
</div>
<div>
Photo: 002.jpg<br />
</div>
<div>
<img src="krajina/003.jpg" alt="krajina"><br />
</div>
<div>
Photo: 003.jpg<br />
</div>
<div>
<img src="krajina/004.jpg" alt="krajina"><br />
</div>
<div>
Photo: 004.jpg<br />
</div>
<div>
<img src="krajina/005.jpg" alt="krajina"><br />
</div>
<div>
Photo: 005.jpg<br />
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Note: I would still keep an array of allowed directories and check against it for security, even if this answer checks the type of file. (I don't think you need to update the answer for that, though)

Comment: It's great piece of code. I think it will work. I need to translate it to human language and involve. : }. Thanks

Comment: @Alessandro. Your code works great. I haven´t realised one thing. Now, when i load page from options, page load and in select option is always name of author at the first of my option. I would need. When i choose the author i need to display his name displayed at the top of option list. Maybe it would be better place some text (name of author or some short text about him) in some div.

Comment: @Alessandro. For example. In option i would add value name or something..'<option name='Jan Viazanicka . Photography: Nature...'  value="http://www.divart.sk/vg/gallery.php?dir=jan-viazanicka">JÁN VIAZANICKA</option>' . Could i display name text on page when i choose a

Comment: It would by the best. Author send me a folder with photos and text file with infomation. Could i include txt file inside some div when option is choosen ?

Comment: option [name](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_name.asp) is not possible... see you [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp)...

Comment: You can use: `<option value="divart.sk/vg/gallery.php?dir=jan_viazanicka">Jan Viazanicka - Photo: Nature</option>`

Comment: @Alessandro. Really thans a lot. As you can see on link http://www.divart.sk/vg/gallery.php i worked your script. I play with idea. How to display file name in gallery screen ? I created it easy with author name when you click button name. But to use basename or something for display name is too complicated.

Comment: @Alessandro. Many thanks for your basic charset solution !!

Comment: @Alessandro. YOU ARE MY HERO !!

Comment: @Alessandro. Hi there again. I thing, this is almost final product of our work and thanks much again. http://onlinegallery.online/index.php . Last thing what i want to do is to add previous button to image slideshow. Following code works for button next at the right top of page.

Comment: @Alessandro                                                                       jQuery(".hidewinnext").on("click keyup", function (e) {
    if (e.type == "click" || e.keyCode == 39) {
       jQuery('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(500)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(500)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
 jQuery('#slideshow > div').css('display','none');
  jQuery('#slideshow > div:first').css('display','flex'); 
 
    }
});  // it would be possible to use this code for previous button after some change ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I only write php, javascript is not my workhorse... see this: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/simple-auto-playing-slideshow/ and this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22116664/jquery-slideshow